# Can I use a snake to clean out a shower head extension?

Tags: shower, water-pressure

I have a basic 25 to 50ft long 1\4 to 3\8 snake, with a 1\2 drill. Can I use that to clean out a shower head extension? I noticed sediment when taking the old shower head off. With the extension installed, the water pressure is poor.  It's a two axis extension, with about a foot between.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't snake a water supply pipe. Does the water come out properly without the extension installed? If so, then the restriction is in the extension.

Comment: I used one of the extensions for a while, since they change the direction of the water 2 times, and the bolt for the wing nut goes through also takes space the water would usually have - all after the shower mixing valve - they do cause problems with water flow. But there is nothing inside to snake, you likely just saw some bits that got inside when it was being made.